# Do .mov files work in html 5 video tags?

Tags: html, html5-video

The mp4 in the following html5 code works with no problem but the .mov file does not.  What's going on here?

```
<video autoplay="" loop="" style="width:100%; height: auto; position:absolute; z-index: -1;">
                <source src="00299.mov" type="video/mov">
                <source src="http://syddev.com/jquery.videoBG/assets/tunnel_animation.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

00299.mov is in the same directory as the html file.  If I comment out the .mp4 file the screen is blank. Otherwise the screen only shows the .mp4 file.

I also tested the file 00299.mov and it works outside the project no problem.

UPDATE:
I now host the file at:
http://files.parsetfss.com/90b6030c-d712-42ec-b2ee…fss-4d5fe3b4-8758-4fb6-a11b-585987a74f56-Date.mp4

I think it has something to do with the file.  I know mp4 works and other mp4 files are working within the project.  I can't figure out why I can't get this particular mp4 to work.

Comment: Is this issue happening on desktop, mobile, or both? What codec was used for the video, is it in the [supported list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML5_video#Table)?

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro it is happening on desktop for sure, as it is on my local machine.  I'm not sure what codec was used for the video as I downloaded from VideoHive. To make sure that the file is compatible I converted from .mov to .mp4. It still doesn't work.  To make sure the file is in a location I can find, I put it in the same place that I put images that I know are working and used the same src="".  Still no dice. Where should I go from here?

Comment: The link to the file is not working